# Magento 1.7 "Cookie Restriction Mode" for EU compliance

Tags: magento, cookies

`Magento 1.7` has added a `Cookie Restriction Mode` which when activated adds a block above the header which asks for consent to set cookies.

However, it appears to set the usual cookies regardless of whether `Allow` is chosen. If you click `Allow` it simply sets a new cookie to that effect, and no longer shows the warning.

Has anyone looked at modifying this so that it won't set the initial cookie, or to add a second `Deny` option that deletes them?

The alternative seems to be to change the text so that is assumes continued use of the site as tacit acceptance of the cookies?

How have/are you going to solve this?

> *Update:* Well, they have changed the new rules at the 11th hour to strongly lean towards tacit acceptance, which simplifies the whole process, and seems to make the Magento module sufficient.

Comment: i'll just ignore the EU regulations as it is insane and 90% EU official sites are not following this. It is like asking a random common person to solve high math in the street you won't get a solution from them as they are as far from knowing high math as they are from knowing what cookie is so they 90% will say no to your question

Comment: I completely agree that the legislation is ill considered, and may indeed be short-lived. An increasing number of larger sites (such as BT) are starting to implement it in a fairly unintrusive way based on assumed consent though.

Comment: the thing is that you can't implement this feature without setting cookies at some point :)

Comment: Aren't they called "biscuits" on that side of the pond?

Comment: I believe that is just a sign that in future versions Magento will be compliant to EU regulations.

Comment: That maybe makes sense. Think I may just modify the text to indicate that continued use implies consent. Seems to be what a lot of other sites have done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, they have changed the new rules at the 11th hour to strongly lean towards tacit acceptance, which simplifies the whole process, and seems to make the Magento module sufficient.

In fact a lot of sites are not even bothering with a pop-up, instead opting for just a link, or at most a briefly visible accordion.